# MySQL: order by query for user defined way

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I have a query where i get data like this:

```
fld_id  | fld_type_id | fld_product
-----------------------------------
    81  |   1         |    25
    82  |   2         |    25
    83  |   3         |    25
    84  |   4         |    25
```

The order of fld_type_id is 1,2,3,4 but what I want is to arrange this order in 3, 4, 2, 1 I tried to do this as:

```
Select * from tbl 
where fld_product = 25 
Order by Case fld_type_id 
when 3 then 1 
when 4 then 2 
when 2 then 3 
else 4
```

but it did'nt helped me... How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `FIELD()`

```
ORDER BY FIELD(fld_type_id, 1, 2, 4, 3) DESC
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/606e8/1)

when `fld_type_id` is not in the list, [it appears below](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7a6b5d/1).

Answer (score 1):

try

```
Select *, 
Case fld_type_id when 3 then 1 
when 4 then 2 
when 2 then 3 
else 4 END as sOrder 
from tbl where fld_product = 25 Order by sOrder
```